# Does it follow that $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $p \in (1, \infty)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Fix a function $\varphi \in C_c^\infty$, $\varphi \not\equiv 0$, and set $u_n(x) = \varphi(x + n)$. Does it follow that $u_n \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$ for all $p \in (1, \infty)$?

Comment: The proof should be quite standard.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The sequence is bounded and, hence, has a weakly convergent subsequence. This subsequence converges strongly in $L^q([-L,L])$ for any $L > 0$. Moreover, it converges to zero pointwise. Hence, the limit must be zero.

Finally, it is straightforward to show that the entire sequence converges towards zero weakly.

Comment: Why the entire sequence converges weakly to $0$ ? I can not see it, thanks

Comment: This is a standard argument: If every subsequence has a (weakly) convergent subsequence with limit $0$, then the whole sequence converges (weakly) towards $0$. The proof is by contradiction: Assume that the sequence does not converge weakly towards $0$. Then there is a subsequence $\{v_n\}$ and some element $\ell$ in the dual space with $|\ell(v_n)| > \epsilon$. But then, you can use the original argument to show that $v_n$ has a subsequence with weak limit $0$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, I know this argument, I just didn't see that since the subsequence converges strongly in $L^q$ (I guess because of a compact embedding ) and pointwise to $0$ then it must converge to $0$ in $L^q$. But from here how does it follow that this subsequence is weakly convergent to $0$ in $W^{1,p}$, i.e why the sequence and its derivatives are weakly convergent in $L^q$ ?

Comment: Oo, I see, sorry !

Comment: One more thing: In your answer, you assume $p\leq q $ in order to have a compact embedding of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^1)$ in $L^q(\mathbb R^1)$, and not the conjugate exponent $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ ?

Comment: If $p > 1$ and $q \in [1,\infty]$, the embedding of $W^{1,p)(\mathbb R^1)$ into $L^q(\mathbb R^1)$ will be compact. $q$ does not need to be the conjugate exponent.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am wandering how is it possible that $u_n\to 0$ in $L^q$, as the $L^q$ norm of each $u_n$ is constant, i.e $\|u_n\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^1)}=const>0,\,\forall n\in\mathbb N$. But on the other hand, we have that if $u_n\to g$ in $L^q$ and $g\neq 0$ a.e then there is a subsequence $u_{n_k}(x)\to g(x)$ a.e, which is a contradiction with that $u_n(x)\to 0$ a.e.

Comment: Ups. The embedding is only compact on bounded domains...

Comment: I think it can be fixed if you argue on bounded subsets.

Comment: Ahaa, I didn't recall that too. Whole day this is orbiting my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T\in W^{-1,p'}(\mathbb{R})$. Then, there are functions $f_1,f_2\in L^{p'}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$T(u)=\int f_1u+\int f_2u',\ \forall\ u\in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}).$$

We have to prove that $T(u_n)\to 0$ for all $T\in W^{-1,p'}(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose that the support of $\varphi$ is contained in $[a,b]$. By one hand $$\left|\int f_1u_n\right|=\left|\int f_1(x)\varphi(x+n)\right|=\left|\int f_1(x-n)\varphi(x)\right|\le \int_a^b |f_1(x-n)\varphi(x)|.$$

The last integral must converge to zero when $n\to\infty$, because it is bounded by $$\left(\int_{a-n}^{b-n}|f_1|^{p'}\right)^{1/p'}\|\varphi\|_p.$$

On the other hand $$\left|\int f_2u_n'\right|\le \int_a^b |f_2(x-n)||\varphi'(x)|,$$

and as in the last case, this integral must converge to zero, therefore, $$|T(u_n)|\le \left|\int f_1u_n\right|+\left|\int f_2u'_n\right|,$$

converges to zero.

Remark: a characterization of $W^{-1,p'}(\mathbb{R})$ in terms of functions in $L^{p'}$ can be found in the Brezis book of Functional Analysis.